# javascript setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a javascript function as shown below.

```js
    function checkEven(number){
      return(number % 2 == 0 ? true : false)

      setTimeout(checkEven(number), 2000)
    }
```

I want to call **checkEven** function within every 2 seconds. but it is not working.

But then I tried the following code. It working fine and print method gets called in every 2 seconds.

```js
    function print(){
      console.log(new Date());
      setTimeout(print, 2000)
    }
```

I want to understand why the first code didn't work. I need help with this.

Comment: In the first code you're not passing a function to `setTimeout`. You're passing the result of a function call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript recursion settimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559510/javascript-recursion-settimeout)

Comment: If you want to call checkEven every 2 seconds, you should use setInterval.

Comment: You are returning data and calling setTimeout only **after**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the function every 2 seconds you should use `setInterval()`:

```
const myLoop = setInterval(myFunc, 2000);

function myFunc() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}

clearInterval(myLoop); //If you want to stop the loop.
```

Also, in your code you are using `setTimeout()` only after the `return`. So, if it worked, the `setTimeout(checkEven(number), 2000)` would have a number as a parameter instead of a Func.